# Exam Result Publishing mysql

Tags: mysql

Hi I am developing Exam result publishing application. I am using mysql database for this. My table structure are like this here I didn't include other basic tables

table **exams**

```
id
name
year_id
semester_id
course_id
level_id
```

table **exam_students**

```
id
exam_id
student_id
exam_type /* regular/partial */
```

table **exam_results**

```
id
exam_id
student_id
subject_id
marks
```

Here **exams** table holds a exam information and students are enrolled in that exam and that information is saved in **exam_students** table and the result are stored in **exam_results**. These are fine for a regular students(who will sit for all the subjects exam) but how do I manage the students who were failed in some subjects last time and only sit for some subjects this time(partial type)

For eg, let say we have 3 subjects x,y and z and student A failed in y subject in last exam and this time he only sit for y subject and if he get pass mark this time in y subject then we will have to publish the result of student A along with the other subjects marks that he already gained and if he fails in that subject again he have to sit for it next time.
So how do I design table for this kind of logic.
Its hard for me to explain please if somebody know websites link to get the information on this it will be great help for me.
Thanks for your any help and suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can have one more table named as "Repeaters". In that, you can have attributes like id, exam_id, student_id and one more that is course_id to make you aware that which course he/she is repeating.